# openssh-server: ChrootDirectory is not allowed within a Match block

Tags: ssh, sftp

My sshd_config looks like this:

```
Match User c_upload
        ChrootDirectoy /var/www/upload
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

`etc/init.d/ssh restart` fails with this message:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 90: Bad configuration option: ChrootDirectoy
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 90: Directive 'ChrootDirectoy' is not allowed within a Match block
```

My openssh-server version (according to dpkg AND ssh -v) is 5.5p1.
According to the manual I should be able to use the ChrootDirectory option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't see for looking you are missing the **r** from `Directory`

```
ChrootDirectory /var/www/upload
```

should do the trick.

Comment: OMG! I am such a blind idiot. That of course did the trick ;-) I even wrote it correctly in the title...

Comment: made the same mistake :) funny that sshd complains not about unknown configuration option :/